# Hide input field and make them 3 separate input fields with jQuery and put the value in the one

Tags: jquery, validation, input, append, hide

Because of validation issues, I don't want to do this by adding the 3 `input fields` via `HTML`. That's why I am going to a `jQuery` approach, but I can't get it to work. I have put my code in `jSFiddle` --> http://jsfiddle.net/qV8Cc/, I hope someone can help me out.

What I want is: you now have 1 input field. This one must not be visible for users (that's why I put it on hide). What I want them to see is 3 separate input fields, side by side instead. I used hide and append for this, but I couldn't get it working. Because I validate just the one input field (the first one we did hide), I want the values that are written in the 3 others, go to the input field that was hidden. Can someone help me out with this please?

Here is the code:

```
$().ready(function(e){
$('.classnameofmyinputfield').hide();
$('.classnameofmyinputfield').parent.append('<input classname><input classname><input classname>');
$('.classnameofmyinputfield').blur(function(e){
    var input = $(this);
    $('.classnameofmyinputfield').val($('.classname').val()+$('.classname').val()+$('.classname').val());


})


});
```

Comment: Other people are getting it, you don't, and you give a downvote? What is wrong with you?

Comment: how can you say that i have downvoted your question.? for kind of your information i really didn't get your question that's why i have commented instead of giving answer of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#profiel_rekeningnummer').parent().append('<input name="field1" id="field1" class="field"/><input name="field2" id="field2" class="field"/><input name="field3" id="field3" class="field"/>');

    $('.field').blur(function(e){
   $('#profiel_rekeningnummer').val($('#field1').val()+$('#field2').val()+$('#field3').val());
        alert($('#profiel_rekeningnummer').val());
    });
});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qV8Cc/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but why do I get dialog boxes and why doesn't it blur it? Do I something wrong?

Edit: I want the values that are inputted in the 3 fields, to be send to the input field that is hidden. Can this be done?

Comment: `profiel_rekeningnummer` is a hidden field, while `field1`, `field2`, `field3` are the visible input fields. The value of these three fields goes to the hidden field which is `profiel_rekeningnummer`

Comment: Thanks man, I removed the `alert`. It still will work, right?

Comment: Thanks. But what about the blur? It does not blur?

Comment: The blur event happens, when you (as user) leave an input field, for example by clicking to another input field. So each time you leave one of the three new input fields, the value of the original field is re-computed.

Comment: What blur? Values goes to hidden field when blur event is called on a field

Comment: Sorry, sorry, I get it now. Thanks mates, appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your `blur` method you need something like:

```
$('input.classname').blur(function() {
    var $hiddeninput = $('.classnameofmyinputfield');
    $hiddeninput .val(''); // clear the hidden field
    $('input.classname').each(function() {
        $hiddeninput .val(hiddeninput.val() + $(this).val()); // add value from each of the 3 shown input fields
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't get it working. Can you help me? This is what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/qV8Cc/1/

Comment: I changed the original field to visible: http://jsfiddle.net/juDJK/ If you now add text to the three new input field, it is also shown in the first one.